# Google Analytics real time tracking without screen view events

Tags: java, android, google-analytics

I've implemented GA in my app like what it stated on the Google Developers page. I was getting real time data, events and screen views just fine.

However, I decided to turn screen view off because I was getting too many screen views events and have to reduce the number of events sent to GA. So I went on to set this attribute to false.

```
    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">false</bool>
```

Well, I was able to get rid of the screen view events in the app, but the real time data isn't being tracked too.

Is there a way to get real time data tracking without having to track screen view events?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Auto activity tracking doesn't have relationship with real time reporting and disabling it should not affect real time reporting. Are you sure you are sending the events you expect to see in the real time? Please enable verbose logging and check logcat for the event hits you send to Analytics.